# Replacing a simple past in passive voice with "past perfect"

Tags: past-perfect, passive-voice

Please help me with changing the sentence below into past perfect tense.

> Of course they didn't fly. because planes weren't invented yet.

Is this correct :

> Of course they didn't fly. because the plane hadn't been invented yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Plane* is a count noun.  You can say *the plane* or *planes* instead.

Comment: @snailplane Thank you snailplane :) other than that is everything ok? Do both sentences sound natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to comment to add my input but not enough reputation i'm afraid.

The second statement seems okay to me, but I think with the first statement it would make more sense to say:

"Of course they didn't fly, because planes **had not yet been** invented."

Comment: Thank you Ray but shouldn't we use "have" when we say "planes".

Comment: If I'm correct that would be if you were speaking in the present tense, "have" would make it seem planes have still not been invented yet. Where as with your statement you are speaking in the past tense, which would make sense to say they **had** not yet been invented.